# PHP sistema de Postagem (Blog)

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo o seguinte [site](http://molbe.freetzi.com/) tenho conhecimento em web designers mas nada em `php`, e preciso criar um sistema de postagem para o site, estou fazendo testes aqui no meu servidor e estou tendo progresso exceto por um problema segue o código em `php`:

```
<article>
  <?php 
    $limitePag = 5;
    if(isset($_GET['pg'])){
        $pg = $_GET['pg'];
        $inicio = ($pg * $limitePag)-$limitePag;
        $sql = mysql_query("select * from postagem order by datapost asc LIMIT $inicio,$limitePag");
        while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $linha['id'];
            $Titulo = $linha['titulopost'];
            $bloco1 = $linha['bloco1'];
            $bloco2 = $linha['bloco2'];
            $datapost = $linha['datapost'];
    ?>
        <div class="article_date luck grid_2 alpha omega"><span class="month"><?php echo date('M',strtotime($datapost)) ?><br/><?php echo date('d',strtotime($datapost)) ?></br/></span><span class="year"><?php echo date('Y',strtotime($datapost)) ?></span></div>
        <div class="grid_9 alpha">
        <h1 class="luck"><?php echo $Titulo ?></h1>
        <p><?php echo $bloco1 ?></p>
    <?php
        $sql = mysql_query("select * from anexo where fk = $id");
        while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $anexo = $linha['foto'];
        $descricao = $linha['descricao'];
        $link = $linha['link'];
    ?>
        <img src="./foto/<?php echo $anexo ?>" alt="" width="529" height="240"/>
        <span class="caption osans-i"><?php echo $descricao ?> - <a href=<?php echo $link ?>><?php echo $link ?></a></span>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
     <p><?php echo $bloco2 ?></p>
    <div class="small_sep"></div>
    </div>
    <?php           
    }}else{
        $pg = 1;
        $inicio = ($pg * $limitePag)-$limitePag;
        $sql = mysql_query("select * from postagem order by datapost asc LIMIT $inicio,$limitePag");
        while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $id = $linha['id'];
            $Titulo = $linha['titulopost'];
            $bloco1 = $linha['bloco1'];
            $bloco2 = $linha['bloco2'];
            $datapost = $linha['datapost'];
    ?>    
    <article>
        <div class="article_date luck grid_2 alpha omega"><span class="month"><?php echo date('M',strtotime($datapost)) ?><br/><?php echo date('d',strtotime($datapost)) ?></br/></span><span class="year"><?php echo date('Y',strtotime($datapost)) ?></span></div>
        <div class="grid_9 alpha">
        <h1 class="luck"><?php echo $Titulo ?></h1>
        <p><?php echo $bloco1 ?></p>
        <?php
            $sql = mysql_query("select * from anexo where fk = $id");
            while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $anexo = $linha['foto'];
            $descricao = $linha['descricao'];
            $link = $linha['link'];
        ?>
            <img src="./foto/<?php echo $anexo ?>" alt="" width="529" height="240"/>
            <span class="caption osans-i"><?php echo $descricao ?> - <a href=<?php echo $link ?>><?php echo $link ?></a></span>
        <?php 
            }
        ?>
        <p><?php echo $bloco2 ?></p>
        <div class="small_sep"></div>
        </div>
    </article>  
    <?php
        }}
    ?>

  <a href="#" class="luck previous">&lt; Prev</a>
  <a href="#" class="luck next">Next &gt;</a>


</div><!--/grid_11 - articles-->
```

estrutura do banco de dados no meu servidor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

é algo bem simples (por enquanto) apenas postagem com possibilidade de incluir fotos, criei um diretório padrão para as fotos que forem postadas `./fotos`, meu problema é o seguinte eu fiz a inserção dos valores com o MySQL tanto em postagem quanto em anexo quando tento recuperar essas informações apenas a primeira postagem aparece na pagina, porem quando eu removo o loop que verifica quantas imagens foram anexadas ele traz todos as postagem, porem sem imagens, quando eu colocou-o novamente ele carrega apenas a primeira postagem e com imagens, o trecho é esse:

```
<?php
 $sql = mysql_query("select * from anexo where fk = $id");
 while($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 $anexo = $linha['foto'];
 $descricao = $linha['descricao'];
 $link = $linha['link'];
?>
  <img src="./foto/<?php echo $anexo ?>" alt="" width="529" height="240"/>
  <span class="caption osans-i"><?php echo $descricao ?> - <a href=<?php echo $link ?>><?php echo $link ?></a></span>
 <?php 
  }
 ?>
```

com loop de anexo:

[image: com o codigo]

sem loop de anexo:

[image: sem o loop de anexo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está sobrescrevendo as variáveis no momento de pegar o "anexo".
Troque o nome das variáveis, exemplo:

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("select * from anexo where fk = $id");
while($linha2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
$anexo = $linha2['foto'];
...
```

Comment: verdade deu certo, obrigado fera!